# Emacs xkcd installation needs JSON 1.4, not found in ELPA

Tags: emacs, json

I tried to install the xkcd emacs package (where you can view an xkcd comic in emacs) and got the following error:

> Need JSON 1.4, but only 1.2 is available

I tried to get JSON 1.4 but I cannot find it in the package manager ELPA.

It also says that I have JSON 1.3 built in and installed. A lot of things seem to not work correctly.

How can I get xkcd to work inside of emacs?

I use Ubuntu 12.04 and Emacs 24.3.

Answer (score 1):

Until json.el v1.4 is available in some ELPA package (after some searching I was not able to find one) the solution would be for you to install xkcd on your own.

You can find xkcd.el on the [github page](https://github.com/vibhavp/emacs-xkcd) for the project. Take the file and save it somewhere on your `load-path`.

Also I'd suggest registering a issue on their github page. It appears that requirement on json v1.4 was committed just today (25 Jan ~9am EST). Perhaps it was a mistake.